# AccountId in Campaign Member - How to deploy standard field?

Tags: administration, fields, change-set, object

In my sandbox, the Campaign Member object has a field `AccountId`, and this field is not custom field, as it does not have `__c`, hence it is standard field.

In my production, the Campaign Member object does not has a field `AccountId`

So, I need to deploy this field to my production, how to deploy the standard field?

Via SFDX does not work:

`Error  CampaignMember.AccountId     fullName must end with: __c or __kav or __x or __b or __e or __p or __mdt or __dll or __dlm`

And via Change Set does not work too: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000I24dQAC

Comment: Are you sure that is a standard field? It is [not listed in the SOAP docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_campaignmember.htm).

Comment: see a screenshot: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/pt-BR/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000FUC7SSAX

Comment: If you would like vus to view an image, [edit] your post to include it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for "Accounts As Campaign Member" In setup

Change the radio button to enable.

The field will be visible in the campaign member

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You cannot deploy standard fields (unless you want to change some attributes of an existing standard field like helptext, label etc) as they must be available in every org by itself. If field is not available in production, it may be due to some license or feature limitation.

I would advise you create support ticket with Salesforce clarifying why that field is not there.

Comment: N.B. - you can deploy some attributes of standard fields - help text, encryption, history tracking, and of course, their related standardValueSets

Comment: @cropredy yes, including label of field. I meant, you cannot create that field to start with. Updated the answer to clarify that.